# Is TreeModel really as bad as I think?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

When I first saw `javax.swing.tree.TreeModel`, I thought it's quite a lot of work to write all the methods. Then I found the `DefaultTreeModel` and thought it will be easy to use for file tree via the Adapter pattern. So I started to write the adapter and sort of failed. I need to be able to access the corresponding File given a `TreeNode` (which is easy since it can be an instance variable), but I need it the other way round as well. This can be solved using a Map, but it ate quite a lot of memory. The switch to `WeakHashMap` helped.

This worked, but I ran into some strange problems when the tree changed. Additionally, it all was really slow since `File.list()` got called many times. There are multiple stupid methods like `getChildCount()`, `getChild(Object parent, int index)`, and `getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child)` and in my naive implementation each call lead to reading a directory.

It all was quite a lot of work and the result was terrible. Sure, my fault, but wasn't it the direct consequence of using a flawed overcomplicated model?

It wouldn't happen, if there was a single method like `List getChildren(Object)` instead. Maybe I did it all wrong, what's the proper way?

<sup>Finally, I wrote `MyCachingTreeModel implements TreeModel` using a *per class* adapter, which solved it all. But I'm still curios how else it could have been solved.</sup>

#### Update:

The above may look like a sort of rant, instead of a proper question. So I try it again:

*How to implement a TreeModel for the filesystem tree efficiently so that it shows the current state of the directories?*

<sup>My solution doesn't count here, as I circumvented the whole model. Moreover, it caches too much and hardly ever notices any changes.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(quite late edit:)

> *How to implement a TreeModel for the filesystem tree efficiently so that it shows the current state of the directories?*

I think there isn't a really good way to show a directory tree with JTree so it is always up-to-date.
The problem is that the model has to notify its listeners (= the JTree) whenever something important changes, and this is only possible if we regularily recheck the files. So your model at least would need an own Thread. Naturally, it should only check those files whose nodes who are actually displayed - but the model does not really know this (can only guess by the last calls of `getValue()`).

Maybe one could combine this with the caching problem: Have a cache of directory objects corresponding to the lastly queried nodes, with a "last checked" time. For some time after the first creation they remain valid, we cache the list of child files, but throw them away later. For these same objects which were queried by the tree, we also some time later look again at the file system, and fire the right change events whenever something is not the same as before.

This still relies on lots of heuristics to know which Files have to be checked - maybe instead we should break the layering and let our model simply ask the Tree which nodes are showing, rechecking (and caching) only those.

---

(Old not-really-an-answer:)

When the TreeModel API was created (at the same time as whole Swing), the collection Framework was not there yet. This is also the reason that we need a Vector (instead of List) at multiple places in Swing.

Comment: I didn't really find a question, it seemed to be more of a rant. So sorry for not answering this. (I did never implement a file system tree - my last TreeModel some days ago was from a in-memory structure consisting mainly of objects with a list of children, so the implementation was quite straightforward, a bit later complicated by having to use filters.)

Comment: Agreed, it was sort of rant. I'm going to reformulate it and make it to a real question.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of having the more complicated API was precisely so that something like `File.list()` doesn't get called so often.  The idea is that for things like counting children which may have to be done many times, you can provide an implementation which does less work than actually getting all the children and then counting them would.

That being said, it doesn't seem like that's really communicated adequately in the API spec, or else you wouldn't have to ask the question. :)

Comment: Even if it was - how should I do it for files? There's no cheaper operation in this case and it'd much faster if they asked for the whole list and used it multiple times instead of asking again and again. There may be situations where their API is better, but I don't know any.

Comment: Yeah, I mean in your case the correct solution is probably to cache the list of files after the first time you get it, and it sounds like that's where you landed.  But you could certainly imagine a situation where you were fetching hierarchical data out of a database, and a COUNT query would be faster than a SELECT query, or maybe you'd even denormalized the number of children on to the parent object.

Answer (score 0):

Also: consider the NetBeans Platform and their Node & Explorer APIs

Comment: I look at it, but it looks very complicated. Did you mentioned it as an "it could get worse" example?